# iOS App Release: Bundle identifier error?

Tags: ios, xcode, release

i have the following Problem with an iOS App Release.
My App is ready to publishing. So i did the following:

- Set an unique Bundle Identifier in xCode
- Set "Automatically manage signing" in xCode
- Then i visit "developer.apple.com > Account > App-ID"
- On this Site, i will create an App-ID with the same Bundle Identifier

But i get an Error, that the Bundle-ID is already in use. I tried this with different IDs.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks for your help

Sebastian

Comment: Xcode has probably already created the app id for you

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you. But i didnt see the app-ID on the surface (developer.apple.com). Where can i see, which app-IDs added by xcode?

Comment: They will be in the list with an XC prefix

Comment: Thank you. But where can i find the list? Under "iOS App IDs" > "App-IDs", there a just the App-IDs, which i have add over the surface on "developer.apple.com"

Comment: That is the list; Are you sure you are logged into Xcode with the same account that you are logging into developer.apple.com with?  If Xcode automatically creates the bundle id under a different account, you can't use it on yours.

Comment: I will check this. Can you tell me, how i can find out, with which account iam logged in in xCode? So i can make sure, if these are the same accounts. Thank you

Comment: It shows on the signing drop down and in preferences->Accounts

Comment: Thank you, i will check is today :) have a nice day

Comment: Now iam sure, that i use the same Apple Account on xCode and on developer.apple.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186812/discussion-between-paulw11-and-sebastian-hock).

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. My apple account was an another as in xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the AppleID you are using to login to https://developer.apple.com is the same account you have configured in Xcode.  If they are different, then Xcode will automatically register the Bundle ID using the account that it has, preventing you from using that same Bundle ID in your other account.